# What is the best way to increment html elements with a list of values(ASP.net)?

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, import

I got a list of Pizza, I would like to automatically import their name in a html element.
I'm wondering what is the best way to work with object or values like that. I was thinking to use Razor language (because I work on ASP.net)but I'm not sure maybe JavaScript could do the job too...?
Could you give me a short example of what my code would look like.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/240/200" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
         **
         <h3>Pizza's name</h3>
         **
         <p>Lorem</p>
         <p><a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-default">Ajouter à ma commande</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> javascript could do the job too.

Yes, you can do that with two approaches, using razor or using java script.

If you want to use razor:

```
 <div class="caption">
    @foreach (var item in ListOfPizza)
    {
       <h3>@item.Name</h3>**
     }
```

Or you can use javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var testData = [{
    "Name": "pizza1"
  }, {
    "Name": "pizza2"
  }];
    
  $.each(testData, function(i, v) {
       
    $('.caption h3').append(v.Name+'<br>');
                     
     }); 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/240/200" alt="">
                    <div class="caption">
                        **<h3></h3>**
                        <p>Lorem</p>
                        <p><a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-default">Ajouter à ma commande</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Note: Here i used test data, which needs to change accordingly!